# NullReferenceException is not managed. "Tables" returns nothing. why?

Tags: vb.net-2010

Here is my code. It's my first time at vb.net.

```
Private Sub Accountnum_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Accountnum.KeyPress
    Dim index As Long = 0
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        Do While index <= 111000
            If Accountnum.Text = ds.Tables("dbo.AccountMaster").Rows(index).Item("AccountNumber").ToString Then
                Nameconsumer.Text = ds.Tables("dbo.AccountMaster").Rows(index).Item("ConsumerName")
                Address.Text = ds.Tables("dbo.AccountMaster").Rows(index).Item("ConsumerAddress")
            End If
        Loop
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: At which line is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The Null Reference error just means that you're attempting to take some action on an object whose value has not been set. It's not uncommon for people to lose sight of the source of these errors when using a language with handy dot notation.

Take a look at an example like line 5 in your snippet: 
ds.Tables("dbo.AccountMaster").Rows(index).Item("AccountNumber").ToString

This isn't uncommon but you're chaining four references together here and assuming that they're all valid. Look at the line that the error occurred on and check each component in your statement for its value. In the line above you would want to check:
 - ds
 - ds.Tables("dbo.AccountMaster")
 - ds.Tables("dbo.AccountMaster").Rows(index)
 - etc.

If any of those are null then the subsequent action that you attempt to take on their result, e.g. ToString will result in a Null Reference exception.

Comment: Adding to this. Sometimes its better to just write lots of lines until  you know which lines can be chained and which could possibly need error checking.